# Font Awesome with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Is it possible to integrate font awesome with activeadmin

I am using the gem and also i have added it in

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile

index do
  column('Inmate') do |letter_response|
    span do
      link_to "E", edit_admin_inmate_path(letter_response.inmate)
      #link_to fa_icon('pencil'), edit_admin_inmate_path(letter_response.inmate), :title =>  'Edit'
      #link_to (content_tag(:i, fa_icon('pencil'))), edit_admin_inmate_path(letter_response.inmate)
    end
    span do
      letter_response.inmate_full_name
    end
  end
end
```

For time being i am using **"E"** to edit, i have tried for others which is commented out as its not loading in front end.

Kindly Suggest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
link_to fa_icon('pencil')
```

You need to load the font-awesome css into the active_admin.scss file.

```
@import "font-awesome";
```

Comment: Icon is loading, but active_admin layout is breaking.

Comment: It Worked.Thanks a lot, Really saved mine so much of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import "font-awesome.css";
```

or `@import "font-awesome.min.css";` if using minified version